# equivalency of Baire's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, soft-question

I was following Introduction to Topology and Modern analysis by G.F. Simmons. There was,

> **Theorem D:** *If $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of nowhere dense sets in a complete metric space $X$, then there exists a point in $X$ which is not in any of the $A_n$'s.*

The proof is straightforward and  there was a equivalent form of **Theorem D** was mentioned,

> **Theorem E:** *If a complete metric space is the union of a sequence of its subsets, then the closure of at least one set in the sequence must have non-empty interior.*

Again they mentioned,

> **Theorem D** and **E** are really one theorem expressed in two different ways. We refer to both (or either) as **Baire's theorem**.

I don't understand the equivalency of those theorem's and how they are same as **Baire's Theorem**? How they are related to each other? And from my last year Real Analysis course, I was only introduced this form of **Baire's Theorem**,

> The set of real numbers of $\mathbb R$ can't be written as the countable union of nowhere-dense sets

What will be the general form of this theorem? Because when I googled, I found [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) only.

Comment: The key parts is to observe that (1) a closed  $E$ is nowhere dense iff $X\setminus E$ is an open dense set (2) In a complete metric space,  the intersection of a countable collection of dense open sets is also dense.

Comment: "the intersection of a countable collection of dense open sets is also dense" This is another equivalent formulation of Baire's Theorem.

Comment: Your "Baire's theorem" from last year is precisely Theorem D applied to the complete metric space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, I saw that now. But I can't interpret the equivalency between **D** and **E**. @OliverDiaz posted an answer (Thanks(+1) for that). I need some time to understand that. Let's see does it clear my doubt or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with your particular text book, but here is a version of Baire's category theorem for complete metric spaces. From this I will try to show you the equivalences to the results in your posting:

> Theorem (Baire): If $X$ is  a complete metric space , then the intersection  of  countable family of open dense sets in $X$  is also dense in $X$.

**Proof:***
Let $\{U_n\}$ be a sequence of dense open sets in $X$. Let $B_0$ be a nonempty open set in $X$. We will show that $B_0\cap\bigcap_nU_n\neq\emptyset$.
Given an integer  $n\geq1$, suppose we have chosen a  nonempty set open set $B_{n-1}$. Since $U_n$ is open and dense,  there is a nonempty open set $B_n$ such that $\overline{B_n}\subset U_n\cap B_{n-1}$ (take $B_n$ to be a ball of diameter less than $1/n$). It is clear that
\begin{align}
K:=\bigcap_{n\geq1}\overline{B_n}\subset B_0\cap \bigcap_n U_n.
\end{align}
Observe that the centers of the balls $B_n$ form a Cauchy sequence,
and  by completeness, $K\neq\emptyset$. $\Box$

The result above is  equivalent to the statement

> Theorem: In a complete metric space $X$, the union of any sequence of nowhere dense has empty interior.

***Proof:***
First notice that $E$ is a closed nowhere dense set iff $X\setminus E$ is an open dense set. This follows from
$$ X\setminus\overline{X\setminus E}=\operatorname{int}\big(X\setminus(X\setminus E)\big)=\operatorname{int}(E)$$

Hence, $\{U_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a sequence of
open dense subsets of $X$ iff $\{X\setminus U_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a sequence of nowhere dense closed sets. Consequently $\bigcap_n U_n$ is dense in $X$ iff $\bigcup_n(X\setminus U_n)$ has empty interior. Therefore, by the Baire category theorem above, in a complete metric space, the union of a sequence $\{E_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of nowhere dense closed sets has empty interior.

From this, the equivalences follow.

Comment: I don't understand $\overline{B_n} \stackrel{?}{\subset} U_n\cap B_{n-1}$ And what's the definition of $B_{n-1}?$ And how $\bigcap_{n\geq1}\overline{B_n}\stackrel{?}{\subset} B_0\cap \bigcap_n U_n$ And Thanks for your response @OliverDiaz

Comment: $B_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-th open set chosen in on the $(n-1)$-th induction step. for $n=1$ ($B_0$) it is an arbitrary non-empty open set. $B_1$ is a ball of diameter less than $1$ and whose closure $\overline{B}_1$ is contained in $B_0\cap U_1$; $B_2$ is an open ball of diameter less than $1/2$ and whose closure $\overline{B}_2$is contained in $B_1\cap U_2$, etc. Density of the $U$'s allows you to do that. Since by construction $\overline{B}_n\subset B_{n-1}\cap U_n$, to follows that $\bigcap_{n\geq1}\overline{B}_n\subset\bigcap_{n\geq1}B_{n-1}\cap U_n\subset\bigcap_{n\geq1}B_0\cap U_n$

Comment: Thanks, again for your response. I still have problem with $K\neq\emptyset$. I understand the centers of the balls $B_n$ form a Cauchy sequence, and being complete the sequence has a limit point but how it justify that $K\stackrel{?}{\neq}\emptyset$. Sorry, if I ask too many questions. @OliverDiaz

Comment: Let $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be the sequence of centers.  Clearly it is a Cauchy sequence since for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_m\in B_n$ for all $m\geq n$, and $\operatorname{dial}(B_n)<\frac{1}{n}$.  As $X$ is complete there is $x\in X$ such that $\lim_nx_n=x$. Then $x\in \overline{B_n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$: every neighborhood of $x$ must contains all but finitely many elements of the sequence $x_n$, that means that any neighborhood of $x$ contains elements of $B_n$ and so, $x_n\in \overline{B_n}$. Therefore, $x\in \bigcap_n\overline{B_n}=K$.

Comment: Sorry, I was forgot to accept your answer. Hope you don't mind. @OliverDiaz. Could you suggest any good book which contain a details examples for metric space and its properties?

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory: The book of Munkers, Topology has many examples on general topological spaces and metric spaces as well.